# Generating Squared Features in a Pandas DataFrame Leads to too many columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When attempting to add features that are multiples of two columns in a Pandas DataFrame, I encounter NaN values. Why does this occur? My intention behind this operation is to obtain squared features for the custom linear regression function implemented using batch gradient descent. And for a data frame having 12 columns, I ended up having 5563 columns.

```
df[col_num] = df.iloc[i]*df.iloc[j]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of input and the matching expected output for clarity

Comment: It looks like you forgot about the colon when multiplying `df.iloc[:, i]*df.iloc[:, j]`

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that you have used the **`.iloc[]`** method incorrectly. When you use **`df.iloc[i]`**, you are actually selecting the i-th row, not the i-th column. Therefore, you are trying to multiply two rows together. When the number of columns is not the same, you will receive NaN values.

To solve this issue, you should select columns instead of rows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 12))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f"col_{i}" for i in range(1, 13)])
print(df)

# example 'col_a' = 'col_1' * 'col_2'
df["col_a"] = df["col_1"] * df["col_2"] # this line
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on taking square of each column (multiplying one column with all others to get input for regression does not make sense!).

```
import pandas as pd
import random 

# Create a list of 10 integers for the ID column
ids = list(range(10))

# Create a list of 10 random numbers for the first numeric column
column1 = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(10)]

# Create a list of 10 random numbers for the second numeric column
column2 = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(10)]

# Create a pandas dataframe with the ID, column1, and column2 columns
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ids,
    "Column1": column1,
    "Column2": column2
})
# Use dictionary comprehension to create squared columns
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'ID']
squared_cols = {f"{col}_square": lambda x, col=col: x[col]**2 for col in cols}

# Assign squared columns to the dataframe
df = df.assign(**squared_cols)
# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```